# How to implement stripe SCA in PHP?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

As per the stripe documentation [here](https://stripe.com/gb/guides/strong-customer-authentication) we read all the information and know the ideas about the SCA. But I am not getting any related API documentation. So, I am confusing how to implement in our existing PHP code and what are the parameters we will add. Please find below my example of code:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(API_KEY_HERE);   

$customer = \Stripe\Token::create(
    array("card" => array(
        "name" => $arg['name'],
        "number" => $arg['number'],
        "exp_month" => $arg['exp_month'],
        "exp_year" => $arg['exp_year'],
        "cvc" => $arg['cvc']
    ))
);
/* some other code here */


$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(
    array(
        "amount" => $arg['amount'],
        "currency" => "usd",
        "description" => "Subscription Charge",
        "customer" => $customer->id
    )
);
/* some other db related code here */
```

I have shared the code. Could you please let us know what we need to change for SCA?

Answer (score 1):

I just answered this question where OP did a great job on the question. 
Perhaps her code can help you see how you need to implement this using JS in the
front-end and PHP in the backend.

[Stripe - Payment Intents (3d secure issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57326265/stripe-payment-intents-3d-secure-issue)

Comment: Thanks for the details. Let me check and will comment here is we face any issue