# Stripe - Payment Intents (3d secure issue)

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments

I did implement Payment intents on my website and now works perfectly with this testing card `4242 4242 4242 4242`, but for other cards that need 3d secure methods, I take this error `"Invalid PaymentIntent status"`.

the Code that I have used is the same standard code that exists on [the Stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/quickstart#manual-confirmation)-flow enriched with some code to manage mysql, emails, metadata etc.

Where do I go wrong? Thanks in Advance.

**simplified js code connected to index.php**

```
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_xxx');
var elements = stripe.elements();
var cardElement = elements.create('card', {style: style});

cardElement.mount('#card-element');

var cardholderName = document.getElementById('cardholder-name');
var cardButton = document.getElementById('card-button');
var amount = $('#amount').val();

cardButton.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    stripe.createPaymentMethod('card', cardElement, {
        billing_details: {name: cardholderName.value}
    }).then(function(result) {

    if (result.error) {


    } else {
      $body.addClass("loading");
      fetch('https://test.com/server.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ 
            payment_method_id: result.paymentMethod.id, 
            amount: amount
            })
      }).then(function(result) {


        // Handle server response (see Step 3)
        result.json().then(function(json) {
          handleServerResponse(json);
        })
      });
    }
  });
});

function handleServerResponse(response) {
  if (response.error) {

  } else if (response.requires_action) {

    stripe.handleCardAction(
      response.payment_intent_client_secret
    ).then(function(result) {
      if (result.error) {

      } else {
        // The card action has been handled
        // The PaymentIntent can be confirmed again on the server
        fetch('https://test.com/server.php', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
          body: JSON.stringify({ 
            payment_method_id: result.paymentMethod.id, 
             amount: amount


          })
        }).then(function(confirmResult) {
            console.log(confirmResult);
          return confirmResult.json();
        }).then(handleServerResponse);
      }
    });
  } else {


  }
}
```

**simplified code on server.php**

```
<?php

  # vendor using composer
  require_once('stripe6400/init.php');

  \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_xxx');

  header('Content-Type: application/json');

  # retrieve json from POST body
  $json_str = file_get_contents('php://input');
  $json_obj = json_decode($json_str);

    $paymentid = $json_obj->payment_method_id;
    $amount = $json_obj->amount;

  $intent = null;
  try {
    if (isset($json_obj->payment_method_id)) {
      # Create the PaymentIntent
      $intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
        'payment_method' => $json_obj->payment_method_id,
        'amount' => $json_obj->amount,
        'payment_method_types' => ["card"],
        'currency' => 'gbp',
        'confirmation_method' => 'manual',
        'confirm' => true,
      ]);
    }
    if (isset($json_obj->payment_intent_id)) {
      $intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::retrieve(
        $json_obj->payment_intent_id
      );
      $intent->confirm();
    }
    generatePaymentResponse($intent);
  } catch (\Stripe\Error\Base $e) {
    # Display error on client
    echo json_encode([
      'error' => $e->getMessage()
    ]);
  }

  function generatePaymentResponse($intent) {
    if ($intent->status == 'requires_action' &&
        $intent->next_action->type == 'use_stripe_sdk') {

      echo json_encode([
        'requires_action' => true,
        'payment_intent_client_secret' => $intent->client_secret
      ]);
    } else if ($intent->status == 'succeeded') {


Stripe\Customer::create([
    "email" => $email,
    "name" => $customer_name,
    "source" => "tok_visa" // obtained with Stripe.js
]);


      echo json_encode([
        "success" => true
      ]);



    } else {
      # Invalid status
      http_response_code(500);
      echo json_encode(['error' => 'Invalid PaymentIntent status']);
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Could you please attach ajax response from your server when using 3d secure card?

Comment: {"error":"Invalid PaymentIntent status"}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you might have the same error I just had. The status of the response from stripe is `requires_source_action` not `requires_action` so your if statement falls through to `Invalid PaymentIntent status`.

```php
// change this
// $intent->status == 'requires_action'

// to this
$intent->status == 'requires_source_action'
```

In my case I'm checking for both so my code is ready for when I do update the stripe SDK.

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/quickstart#confirm-again
(line 33 in the code)

Comment: i no longer get an error, but payment is not being registered, pls give me a while to see what could be an issue

Comment: i did update 'requires_action' to 'requires_source_action' and off we go 3d secure showed up but i got next problem coming from function handleServerResponse(response)    >> TypeError: result.paymentMethod is undefined

Comment: It looks like your sending `payment_method_id` when you should be sending `payment_intent_id: paymentIntent.id`. Check line 17 of the code example: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/quickstart#handling-next-actions

Answer (score 1):

Also on *Customer::create* your source attribute **"tok_visa"** must be a real **token.id** from create token in javascript https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#stripe-create-token